# Lookbehind in python

Tags: python, regex

Suppose I have:

```
string = "2 dogs. 4 cats. 9 horses. 7 goats"
```

I want to match every word that precedes a number.

I tried:

```
matches = re.search(r"(?<=\d+) \w+", string)
```

but it isn't working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> s = "2 dogs. 4 cats. horses. 7 goats"
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'\d+\s(\w+)', s)
['dogs', 'cats', 'goats']
```

Comment: excellent! may I ask why it doesn't include the numbers in the match?

Comment: Because only words are surrounded by parentheses `(\w+)`. See http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax, The `(...)` part.